# What are Clojure's Naming Conventions?

Tags: clojure, naming-conventions

Can anyone explain or point me to where I can find clojure's naming conventions for:

1. File names
2. Functions (From what I understand, function names are simply dash separated values)
3. Variables

Answer (score 54):

You might want to look at the [Clojure library coding standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards) on the developer Wiki - this is probably the most comprehensive list that I've seen.

**Update**: link above seems to be dead, consider instead: https://clojure.org/dev/contrib_howto#_coding_guidelines

To your specific points:

1. File names are lowercase, and stored in a directory structure to match the namespace, and end in .clj e.g. "my/special/namespace.clj
2. Functions are dash-separated-lowercase-words, ideally descriptively chosen so that your code is clear and self-documenting. Don't be afraid to re-use good function names in different namespaces (that is what namespaces are for!).
3. Variables (by which I assume you mean parameters, let-bound variables etc.) are also usually dash-separated-lowercase-words. Since code-is-data, I think it is appropriate that functions and data have the same naming convention :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link. As a follow-up, are file names dash separated as well, i.e. `this/is/a/file-parser.clj`

Comment: @tmore - yes I believe so, as long as it matches the namespace

Comment: No, you must replace hyphens with underscores in filenames.  (Namespace `a-b/c-d` must reside in `a_b/c_d.clj`.)  It's part of the name-munging Clojure has to do to interop with Java properly.

Comment: One clarifying point for Clojure 1.2.1: when you `import` a Clojure record, you must refer to where it is located with an underscore *in your Clojure code* rather than the usual dash. See http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-432

Comment: Sadly the link above now gives a 403

Comment: The page possibly is now this: https://clojure.org/dev/contrib_howto#_coding_guidelines

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at [this non official style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide).

Comment: It even has a nice website today https://guide.clojure.style/#naming

Answer (score 12):

There are some interesting [guidelines on naming written by Stuart Sierra](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/01/09/how-to-name-clojure-functions) which suggest that:

- pure functions should be nouns describing the return value (`age` instead of `calculate-age`)
- side-effecting functions should be verbs describing the action (`create-` for constructing and `get-` for retrieving), reserving the bang `swap!` changes to mutable references.
- verbs that can also be nouns should be distinguished as verb phrases (`send-message` instead of `message`)
- coercions should name the output type without an arrow prefix (`connection` instead of `->connection`) except when the input type must be explicit (`input-type->output-type`)
- namespace aliases can save on repetition (`products/price` instead of `products/product-price`) and prevent local clashes in let bindings
- functions returning functions should have the `-fn` suffix

Answer (score 3):

There is an interesting set of naming conventions documented in a comment by
Taoensso in his
[Encore library](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/encore/blob/f2450b7a12712b7553bb61603e6e98ac75d4a34d/src/taoensso/encore.cljc#L12-L27).

He proposes names using `!` for side-effects, `?` for booleans,
`$` for expensive operations, `_` as dereffable,
`*` for macros; plus a few other combos.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didn't ask for it explicitly, I'll explain what I've seen for protocol naming conventions.

Typically, the name starts with an uppercase "I" and then the rest is camel case, where the first letter of each word is capitalized, and the rest is lower case. For example, I want to define a protocol for rocket ships, I'd use the name IRocketShip

I've also seen 'A' instead of 'I' used, probably to represent the word 'abstract'.

Comment: One of the primary places I've seen this is in CLJS where the protocols are emulating the Java interfaces in CLJ, but I don't think this is a general recommendation. For example, see Rich's protocols in core.async: https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/protocols.clj