# What's the usual naming rule in clojure?

Tags: clojure, naming, naming-conventions

As i see, clojure has more characters for variable name than c/c++/java. For example:

Functions end with '?' usually return a Boolean, they are predicate.

There are also variables starting with '-', or ending with '!'.

i think these are all clojure-style naming. So, what's the usual naming rule in clojure? is there something in common for clojure programmers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of a 2011 question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709131/what-are-clojures-naming-conventions

Answer (score 25):

It's worth looking at Clojure's [Library Coding Standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards) which I think are still probably the best reference on Clojure coding style.

The main function naming conventions seem to be:

- Use lowercase function names: `frobnicate`
- Multiple word names use hyphens as separators: `frobnicate-with-extra-fizz`
- Use namespaces to allow you to re-use good names if needed: `my.special.collection/concat`
- Use `?` to indicate a predicate that returns true or false: `sequential?`
- Use `!` to indicate a function with side effects that is not transaction safe, e.g.: `set!`

For local variables the following are common:

- `f`, `g`, `h` - functions
- `n` - integer representing a size or count
- `index`, `i` - integer index
- `x`, `y` - numbers
- `s` - string input
- `coll` - a collection
- `pred` - a predicate closure
- `& more` - variadic input

Comment: I have sometimes seen some functions named with an * at the end, like foo*. What does the * mean?

Comment: This is a good answer but I have one nitpick. I think `?` should only be used for functions that actually return `true` or `false`. See the linked doc: "Use '?' suffix for predicates. N.B. - predicates return booleans". An example of this in core is [`some`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some) and [`every?`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/every?).

Comment: @dAni: I edited in stuff about `foo*` (and `*foo*` for good measure.)

Answer (score 2):

Clojure is a dialect of Lisp, so Lisp convention may apply: http://www.cliki.net/naming%20conventions

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Library Coding Standards mentioned by @mikera, there is now a (community-driven) Clojure style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide